# Python unable to access multiple GB of my ram?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, out-of-memory

I'm writing a machine learning project for some fun but I have run into an interesting error that I can't seem to fix. I'm using Sklearn (LinearSVC, train_test_split), numpy, and a few other small libraries like collections.

The project is a comment classifier - You put in a comment, it spits out a classification. The problem I'm running into is that a Memory Error (Unable to allocate 673. MiB for an array with shape (7384, 11947) and data type float64) when doing a train_test_split to check the classifier accuracy, specifically when I call model.fit.

There are 11947 unique words that my program finds, and I have a large training sample (14,769), but I've never had an issue where I run out of RAM. The problem is, I'm not running out of RAM. I have 32 GB, but the program ends up using less than 1gb before it gives up.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: You may be running a 32bit version of Python. In a terminal, what does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.maxsize)"` show?

Comment: 2147483647 - I'm assuming this is bits?

Comment: Yes, you are running a 32bit version of Python. That is actually the maximum size of a variable of type `Py_ssize_t` in the CPython implementation. Basically, it's the maximum size you can use as an index. In 32-bit versions, this will be 2**(32-1) == 2147483648`. The maximum amount of address space a 32bit process can hold is `2**32`, depending on your operating system, though, it can be as low as 1-2 gigs (e.g. Windows) because the OS can make the limit lower. If you are going to need more than that, you must use a 64bit version of Python

Comment: Just got done trying that - it works now. Thank you!

Comment: If this solves your problem, I would recommend that you either post an answer or delete the question.

Comment: I tried to make an answer but it told me I couldn't.